# How to check if a template parameter in a function matches a specialization of a given type alias

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, type-alias

I have the following code:

```
template <template <class...> class Temp, class Specialization>
struct IsSpecialization : std::false_type {};


template <template <typename...> class Temp1,
          template <typename...> class Temp2, typename... Ts>
struct IsSpecialization<Temp1, Temp2<Ts...>>
    : std::is_same<Temp1<Ts...>, Temp2<Ts...>> {};

struct ExprKindMerge {};
struct ExprKindSequence {};

template <class Tag, class... Args>
struct Expr {
    std::tuple<Args...> tup;

    constexpr std::tuple<Args...> toStdTuple() const {
        return this->tup;
    }

    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept {
        return std::tuple_size<decltype(tup)>{};
    }
};

template <class...Args>
using MergeExpr = Expr<ExprKindMerge, Args...>;

template <class...Args>
using SequenceExpr = Expr<ExprKindSequence, Args...>;
```

And this function, which sometimes receives a `SequenceExpr<Something>` as the template parameter:

```
template <class FullExpr>
auto f(FullExpr expr) {
    ///**************THIS RETURNS FALSE I EXPECT TRUE
    ///Type of full expr is Expr<ExprKindSequence, ...> which is
    /// the expansion of SequenceExpr<...>
    if constexpr (IsSpecialization<SequenceExpr, FullExpr>::value) 
    //...
}
```

I want to be able to detect if `FullExpr` is a specialization of `SequenceExpr` but it fails for some unknown reason.

Comment: But you're interested in a single type-traits `IsSpecialization` that detect if a type is specialization of a generic container or you're interested in checkig only `SequenceExpr` (and, maybe, a very short list of aliases)?

Comment: @max66 I want to know if what my function receives at the toplevel FullExpr is a SequenceExpr<....> or not. SequenceExpr<...> is an alias for Expr<ExprKindSequence, ...>.

Comment: "It fails for some unknown reason" - how does it exactly fail?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan I changed that before. Maybe not refreshed yet wait a couple of minutes and refresh.

Comment: @VTT true. Not the gist of this anyway. In fact I am doing something slightly differnt but that will do for illustration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why it fails is easy. For a `SequenceExpr<ExtraArgs...>`, `Temp2` is deduced to be `Expr` and `Ts...` is deduced to be `ExprKindSequence, ExtraArgs...`. Then `Temp1<Ts...>` is `Expr<ExprKindSequence, ExprKindSequence, ExtraArgs...>` and is obviously not the same as `Temp2<Ts...>`.

I know of no fully generic way to do this. After all, such a hypothetical template would presumably need to return `true` for `IsSpecialization<std::remove_reference_t, int>`...

If we limit it to alias templates that use their parameters in deducible contexts (which is the case in your example), then one possible way is to ask the question "Can I deduce the `Ts...` in `Temp<Ts...>` from `Specialization`?":

```
namespace detail {
    template<class> class type {};
    template<template<class...> class Temp, class...Ts>
    void try_deduce(type<Temp<Ts...>>);
}

template <template <class...> class, class, class = void>
struct IsSpecialization : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class Temp, class Specialization>
struct IsSpecialization<Temp, Specialization, 
                        decltype(detail::try_deduce<Temp>(detail::type<Specialization>()))>
    : std::true_type {};

static_assert(IsSpecialization<SequenceExpr, SequenceExpr<int>>()());
static_assert(IsSpecialization<Expr, SequenceExpr<int>>()());
static_assert(!IsSpecialization<MergeExpr, SequenceExpr<int>>()());
static_assert(!IsSpecialization<SequenceExpr, MergeExpr<int>>()());
```

Answer (score 1):

If your interested **only** in detecting specializations of `SequenceExpr`, the best I can imagine is to add a specialization of `IsSpecialization` defined as follows

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct IsSpecialization<SequenceExpr, Expr<ExprKindSequence, Ts...>>
    : std::true_type
 { };
```

Obviously this isn't a general solution that I don't think it's possible.

Take in count that if you call `f` with a (by example) `Expr<ExprKindSequence, int, long>` value

```
f(Expr<ExprKindSequence, int, long>{});  // result true !!!
```

the specialization of `IsSpecialization` above match and you get `true`; I don't know if is what do you want.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <template <typename...> typename Temp, typename Specialization>
struct IsSpecialization : std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class Temp1,
          template <typename...> class Temp2, typename... Ts>
struct IsSpecialization<Temp1, Temp2<Ts...>>
    : std::is_same<Temp1<Ts...>, Temp2<Ts...>>
 { };

struct ExprKindMerge {};
struct ExprKindSequence {};

template <typename Tag, typename... Args>
struct Expr
 {
    std::tuple<Args...> tup;

    constexpr std::tuple<Args...> toStdTuple () const
     { return this->tup; }

    constexpr std::size_t size () const noexcept
     { return std::tuple_size<decltype(tup)>{}; }
 };

template <typename ... Args>
using MergeExpr = Expr<ExprKindMerge, Args...>;

template <typename ... Args>
using SequenceExpr = Expr<ExprKindSequence, Args...>;

template <typename ... Ts>
struct IsSpecialization<SequenceExpr, Expr<ExprKindSequence, Ts...>>
    : std::true_type
 { };

template <class FE>
auto f (FE expr)
 { std::cout << IsSpecialization<SequenceExpr, FE>::value << std::endl; }

int main ()
 {
   f(SequenceExpr<int, long>{});             // print 1
   f(Expr<ExprKindSequence, int, long>{});   // print 1  (?)
   f(Expr<int, long>{});                     // print 0
   f(int{});                                 // print 0
 }
```